# LtSpice: how to make a periodic PWL source?

Tags: voltage, ltspice, simulation

I have the following file which describe times and voltage to drive a PWL source.

```
5ms 1.40
5.0001ms 1.45 
10ms 1.45
10.0001ms 1.50 
15ms 1.50
15.0001ms 1.55 
20ms 1.55
20.0001ms 1.60 
25ms 1.60
25.0001ms 1.65 
30ms 1.65
30.0001ms 1.70 
35ms 1.70
35.0001ms 1.75 
40ms 1.75
40.0001ms 1.80 
45ms 1.80
45.0001ms 1.85 
50ms 1.85
50.0001ms 1.90 
55ms 1.90
55.0001ms 1.95 
60ms 1.95
60.00001ms 2.00 
65ms 2.00
65.0000001ms 2.05 
70ms 2.05
70.0000001ms 2.10 
75ms 2.10
75.0000100ms 2.15 
80ms 2.15
80.0000001ms 2.20 
85ms 2.20
85.0000001ms 2.25 
90ms 2.25
90.0000001ms 2.30 
95ms 2.30
95.00001ms 2.35 
100ms 2.35
```

I would like to make this PWL function a periodic one. How can I do it?

Comment: How exact does it need to be?

Comment: Put the values in a text file and use `PWL repeat forever (file="FILENAME.TXT") endrepeat` as shown in this article: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-piecewise-linear-functions-for-voltage-current-sources.html

Comment: `PWL repeat forever (file="FILENAME.TXT") endrepeat` is the solution! @SteKulov

Comment: Hint: instead of writing `85m 1 85.000001m 2`, you can write `85m 1 +1n 2`. The `+` will make the value relative to the previous.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen okay, there is no way to do that change in 0 time, right? (To be such to avoid adding +1n)

Comment: @Lisa No, that would be a physical impossibility. And a nuissance in terms of simulation, since it will only be a cause for convergence failures due to the riduculous timesteps. As far as simulations go, it's a very common choice to use a 1000x...10000x times smaller riseing/falling edge compared to Ton or T, so your code is just fine. But it looks like what you want is a sampled waveform. If so, It's better to get accustomed with `[SpecialFunctions]/sample`.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen what do yo mean for `[SpecialFunctions]/sample` ?

Comment: @Lisa When you're editing your schematic and press `F2` to bring up the component browser, look in the `[SpecialFunctions]` folder for a device named `sample`. If you're not sure what it does and how to use it, lok through the default `Examples/Educational` folder (that came with your installation of LTspice), or in the help (`LTspice > Circuit Elements > A. ...`), or on the [ltwiki](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Main_Page).